# Origin header is "null" in XHR requests in iFrame

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, cors

We have micro-service that allows CORS using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. It works fine. However we have a complicated setup:

`subdomain-A.welt.de` has an iFrame that points to `subdomain-B.welt.de`. `subdomain-B.welt.de` calls the micro-service (somewhere else) via `XHR` and requires CORS.

Within that iFrame, and only there, `subdomain-B.welt.de` sends `null` as `Origin`-header for every `XHR`-request.

I am not absolutely certain on what's the cause of this and in my research I stumbled upon `document.domain`, but as I am uncertain I don't know if that is something to consider (or the right way to fix whatever is happening here).

Comment: This may be due either to an iframe’s `sandbox` value not containing `allow-same-origin` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765536/441757) or due to a request getting redirected from a URL at one origin to one at a different origin (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549369/iframe-sends-origin-as-null#comment93966138_53549369). For both cases, browsers set the origin to null. To fix: add `allow-same-origin` to the `sandbox` value, or eliminate the cross-origin redirect. For other cases where browsers set the origin to null, see the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42242802/441757.