# Origin header null for XHR request made from <iframe> with sandbox attribute

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have a project where I am trying download some data in a tab separated value format from a datahandler however, Google Chrome is sending a null value for the Origin header value.

I'm seeing this when I navigate to http://server.corp.somebiz.com/reportpages/Report_Page_Requests_Over_Time.aspx?app=76ac42b7-ba6f-4be4-b297-758ebc9fe615

```
var url = 'http://server.corp.somebiz.com/DataHandlers/ReportSets.ashx?task=pagerequestsovertime&app=188d1956-c4a7-42f7-9bdd-38f54c14e125&format=tsv';

d3.tsv(url, function(d) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  d.close = +d.close;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  console.log('Do stuff');
});
```

Here are the raw headers on the request:

```
GET /DataHandlers/ReportSets.ashx?task=pagerequestsovertime&app=786b5ef3-1389-4890-8004-533fd1f66f16&format=tsv HTTP/1.1
Host: server.corp.somebiz.com
Connection: keep-alive
accept: text/tab-separated-values,*/*
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

This ends with an error on the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://server.corp.somebiz.com/DataHandlers/ReportSets.ashx?task=pagere…6ac42b7-ba6f-4be4-b297-758ebc9fe615&start=2/1/2017&end=3/2/2017&format=tsv. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://server.corp.somebiz.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Not only am I looking for the why is this happening, what the conditions are that leads to Chrome sending a null Origin header to the server.

This seems to be a Chrome specific issue as Internet Explorer 11 is sending the proper Origin value to the server.

Update: To add another wrinkle, that may or may not be a contributing factor.

I load the calling page in an `<iframe>` element to isolate scripted elements. Calling the page outside of the iframe causes a different behavior, the Origin header on Chrome is missing entirely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456538/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: Are you running your code from a `file://` url? That causes this problem. If that's the case, you will need to run on a local server at least instead.

Comment: No, I'm not using file:// in the URL at all. The data handler builds the request on the fly through an HTTP GET based on a stored procedure that dynamically pulls data from the database. (I also looked at that possible duplicate question and it does not apply.)

Comment: To be clear, by URL I mean the url of the page that your code is running on(i.e as seen in Chrome address bar when running your app), not the value of your `url` variable that you are making the request to in your code.

Comment: No, the page making the call is http://server.corp.somebiz.com/reportpages/Report_Page_Requests_Over_Time.aspx?app=76ac42b7-ba6f-4be4-b297-758ebc9fe615

Comment: Ok, I did think that, just making sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `iframe` you’re loading the calling page in has a `sandbox` attribute that doesn’t contain the value `allow-same-origin`, [browsers give it a “unique” origin](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#the-iframe-element:concept-origin-2):

> When the [`sandbox`] attribute is set, the content is treated as being from a unique origin, forms, scripts, and various potentially annoying APIs are disabled, links are prevented from targeting other browsing contexts, and plugins are secured. The `allow-same-origin` keyword causes the content to be treated as being from its real origin instead of forcing it into a unique origin

…and when determining the value of the `Origin` header to send in a cross-origin request, browsers serialize any unique origin as `null` and give the `Origin` header that value.