# Links don't work if the page was requested with 'null' as origin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, cors, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a standard Rails `5.2.2` app.

On one of my pages I have an iFrame. When I, from within the iFrame, follow a link that opens my website in a new tab, like this:

```html
<iframe src="/page.html" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms allow-top-navigation allow-popups">
  <a href="http://0.0.0.0:3005/" target="_blank">Visit the frontpage</a>
</iframe>
```

I get to the site alright, and my log looks fine:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-11-11 13:10:09 +0100
Processing by StaticPagesController#index as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 408ms (Views: 405.0ms)
```

But no internal links on the page work. When I click a link, this stacktrace is printed before I get redirected back to the page that I came from:

```
Started OPTIONS "/somewhere" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-11-11 13:10:11 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/somewhere"):

.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-11-11 13:10:12 +0100
Processing by StaticPagesController#index as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 394ms (Views: 390.3ms)
```

Just to see what happens, I add to my routes file:

```rb
match "/somewhere", to: "somewhere#somewhere", via: [:options]
```

If I don't protect that page with authentication, no stacktrace is triggered, but I'm redirected back where I came from:

```
Started OPTIONS "/somewhere" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-11-11 13:41:18 +0100
Processing by SomewhereController#somewhere as */*
Completed 200 OK in 625ms (Views: 602.3ms)
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-11-11 13:41:19 +0100
Processing by StaticPagesController#index as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 413ms (Views: 409.8ms)
```

And if I add Devise authentication to the page, this stacktrace is shown:

```
Started OPTIONS "/somewhere" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-11-11 13:33:31 +0100
Processing by SomewhereController#somewhere as */*
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (The browser returned a 'null' origin for a request with origin-based forgery protection turned on. This usually
means you have the 'no-referrer' Referrer-Policy header enabled, or that the request came from a site that
refused to give its origin. This makes it impossible for Rails to verify the source of the requests. Likely the
best solution is to change your referrer policy to something less strict like same-origin or strict-same-origin.
If you cannot change the referrer policy, you can disable origin checking with the
Rails.application.config.action_controller.forgery_protection_origin_check setting.
):

.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:433:in `valid_request_origin?'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:291:in `verified_request?'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:230:in `verify_authenticity_token'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:426:in `block in make_lambda'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:179:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:180:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `block in invoke_before'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `each'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `invoke_before'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.2.2/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/web-console-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
.gems/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-11-11 13:33:31 +0100
Processing by StaticPagesController#index as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 681ms (Views: 677.9ms)
```

The following trick, as suggested in the stacktrace, did not change anything:

```rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_controller.forgery_protection_origin_check = false
end
```

I also tried, [as suggested here](https://www.marksayson.com/blog/setting_http_security_headers_in_rails/#setting-security-headers-in-rails), setting `action_dispatch.default_headers` to various values, without any luck:

```rb
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
  'Referrer-Policy' => 'no-referrer'
}
```

Any idea what happens?

Comment: Try adding `allow-same-origin` to the value of the `sandbox` attribute for that iframe. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765536/441757. If you don’t include `allow-same-origin` in the `sandbox` value, then browsers set the origin to null, and that’s what’s causing Rails to respond with that error — it’s not allowing requests from a null origin.

Comment: Interesting, that solved it. However, adding the allow-same-origin attribute exposes the parent document to the iframe. Any idea how I could avoid that? Would it help to serve the iFrame from a different domain?

Comment: If you want avoid the iframe having access to the parent document, then yeah, serving the iframe from a different origin would have the effect of blocking that access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either mention `* or the host name with the post` for  `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` in the service to Avoid CORS issue and get the Authentication Token :

```
# in config/application.rb
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => 'http://my-web-service-consumer-site.com',
    'Access-Control-Request-Method' => %w{GET POST OPTIONS}.join(",")
  }
```

Source :

https://medium.com/@Nicholson85/handling-cors-issues-in-your-rails-api-120dfbcb8a24
https://demisx.github.io/rails-api/2014/02/18/configure-accept-headers-cors.html