# SCORM: SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame FOR SAME ORIGIN

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, same-origin-policy, scorm

I am aware there are plenty of similar questions, the only difference is I get this for two pages I serve from the **same ** domain. This can be seen in the example below.

```
    Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://content.samba.net" from accessing a cross-origin frame. 
  
at findAPI (https://content.samba.net/00/07/19-10/scorm_support/scorm_support.js:14:10)   
at getAPI (https://content.samba.net/00/07/19-10/scorm_support/scorm_support.js:61:13)   
at https://content.samba.net/00/07/19-10/SCORM.htm:200:16
```

Shouldn't this happen only between different domains?

============================== EDIT =======================================
Ofcourse, few seconds after I posted, I found the issue. The SCORM package has a function to locate the SCORM API. It looks at top and opener. In my case the Window Opener is in a different domain, It was trying to access that.
I'll leave it for history sake. My answer has the details.

Comment: If the iframe has the `sandbox` attribute, try adding `allow-same-origin` to the value. The reason is, without `allow-same-origin` included, browsers set the origin of the iframe to null — and a request from a `https://content.samba.net` to a null origin is a cross-origin request. See the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765536/441757 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289103/same-origin-request-causes-access-control-allow-origin-doesn-t-match-error-th#comment110174397_62289103 and for a lot more details than you probably want, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42242802/441757

Comment: @sideshowbarker that is interesting to know, but my issue was actually much more trivial and simple - I edited my question to reflect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved, and it is specific to the SCORM protocol.
When you open a piece of SCORM content, which is a bunch of html,flash,js and other media files, the first thing it does is trying to find the SCORM api.
The SCORM api is JS that has to be in the window that loads the SCORM content.
In some SCORM packages, the function that looks for the API, looks recursively for the TOP window, i.e. the initial window that started the entire process.
In my case it was a window on my site, that poped the SCORM launcher on my CDN, which has a different domain name.

All I had to do to solve this issue, is cheat the browser to think the SCORM launcher (the window I poped on the CDN) is the TOP, by adding the following two js lines in it:

```
window.top=window;
window.opener=window;
```

Comment: Tried adding this on my parent page doesn't seem to work still getting the same issue

Comment: @oma0256 are they the same domain? PArent page and SCORM window?

Comment: Nope different domains

Comment: @oma0256 the window that holds the SCORM API , I believe (although there might be a way around it) has to beon the same domain as the content - thats how I do it.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka
Hello, do you have any example code for this? I've tried to integrate SCORM for my project and still failed, the last error i've got is this cors things. If you manage to share me some of the example it'll be really helpful, Thank you!

Comment: @Potamir enroll to this https://www.sitelms.org/catalog/course/details/?course_id=5523&mode=enroll&name=Medical+Ethics and then launch the content.... and then view source